# Finding the maximum and minimum on a constraint.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Let $f(x,y,z) = 2x + y$. Find the absolute maximum and minimum on the constraint $x+y+z=1$ So we know that $\nabla f(x,y,z) = \lambda \nabla g(x,y,z)$ where $g(x,y,z) = x+y+z-1$. Calculating, we receive $\nabla f(x,y,z) = (2,1,0)$ and $\lambda \nabla g(x,y,z) = (\lambda , \lambda , \lambda )$ This creates the system of linear equations $$2=\lambda \\ 1=\lambda \\ 0=\lambda \\ x+y+z=1$$ I'm not quite sure what this implies. We can see that $$\lambda \nabla g(x,y,z) = (0, 0, 0) = \nabla f(x,y,z)$$ However we calculated $\nabla f(x,y,z) = (2,1,0)$ Does this imply that there is no maximum or minimum on this constraint?

Comment: You're right in thinking it doesn't have a min or max.  If you think about it, you could make $x$ and $y$ arbitrarily large such that $f$ gets very large, and then just let $z=1-x-y$ to satisfy the constraint.  Same for very large negative numbers.

Comment: By itself, the only thing that the results for the Lagrange-multiplier tells us is that there is no place on the plane $ \ x + y + z \ = \ 1 $ where the normal vector has the direction $ \ \langle 2, \ 1, \ 0 \rangle \ $ .  So there is no "level surface"  $ \ 2x \ + \ y \ = \ c \ $ which is tangent to the constraint plane at any point.  This would be unsurprising since the normal vectors $ \ \langle 2, \ 1, \ 0 \rangle \ $ and $ \ \langle 1, \ 1, \ 1 \rangle \ $ are neither parallel or anti-parallel.  The method is thus of no help:  we must instead consider the infinite extent (continued)

Comment: of the constraint plane, as **Brent** remarks, and that for any "level surface" of $ \ f \ $ , there will always be points of intersection with the constraint plane.  This is what indicates that there are no absolute extrema for the function.  (Were a condition to be imposed such as requiring all three variables to be non-negative, the problem would have a solution.)